# .less files don't get loaded correctly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I installed bootstrap with less for my new website. In my opinion there are not all .less-files compiled correctly. the content should scale down in a fluid way, when I resize the browser window. I tried also with the bootstrap.css (without LESS) and was working fine.

Thanks for your helpful tipps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to `bootstrap.less` you need to also include `responsive.less`